# Overlapping nodes in tree drawing

Tags: tikz-trees

Question: I am stuck in drawing of tree. Actual problem is i wish to draw two more nodes(having names H and I) exactly below to node F. but i couldn't problem is of overlapping of nodes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [circle,draw]{A} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
        child { node [circle,draw]{B} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
            child {node [circle,draw] {D}
                child[missing]
                child {node [circle,draw]{G}}}
            child {node [circle,draw]{F}}
        }
        child {node [circle,draw] {C} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
            child {node [circle,draw] {E}
                child[missing]                  
                child {node [circle, draw] {J}} 
            }
            child {node [circle,draw] {F}
                child[missing]                  
                child {node [circle, draw] {K}} 
            }
                };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the `D` node a bit to the left to make room, with e.g.

```
node [circle,draw,xshift=-5mm] {D}
```

and perhaps also reduce the distance between `H` and `I` the same way you did earlier, with

```
node [circle,draw]{F} [sibling distance=7mm] child {node[circle,draw]{H}} child {node[circle,draw]{I}}
```

If you don't need to emphasize the `missing` children, then no shifting is needed, but I don't know if that is OK. Anyways, see the second example in the code below for that. In the first two examples below I used `\path[every node/.style={circle,draw}]` followed by the tree, then you don't have to specify `[circle, draw]` for every single node.

Another, more automated, method for drawing trees is the `forest` package. I added an example of that as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest} % loads tikz
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Small adjustments:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
         node {A} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
        child { node {B} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
            child {node [xshift=-5mm] {D}
                child[missing]
                child {node {G}}}
            child {node {F} [sibling distance=7mm]
                child {node{H}}
                child {node{I}}}
        }
        child {node  {C} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
            child {node  {E}
                child[missing]                  
                child {node {J}} 
            }
            child {node  {F}
                child[missing]                  
                child {node {K}} 
            }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}

Larger adjustments:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
     node {A} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
        child { node {B} [sibling distance=13mm]
            child {node {D}
                child {node {G}}}
            child {node {F} [sibling distance=10mm]
                child {node{H}}
                child {node{I}}}
        }
        child {node  {C} [sibling distance=10mm]
            child {node  {E}
                child {node {J}} 
            }
            child {node  {F}             
                child {node {K}} 
            }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}

Forest:

\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,circle}
[A 
 [B
  [D [G] ]
  [F [H] [I] ]
 ]
 [C
  [E [J]]
  [F [K]]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great work done by you. Millions thanks.

Comment: Might want to add a minimum size to avoid some circles coming out smaller than others?